# Which verb to use to express a realistic wish

Tags: tense

Lets say I want to make my birthday wish

> 1:I wish I get the tickets to the Super Bowl(like a lottery).
>
> 2:I wish I would get the tickets to the Super Bowl,

All of the grammar websites I have referred to so far regarding tense usage with *wish* tell me it is used with either a **past tense** or a **past perfect** for regrets or past wishes.

> I wish I had a car.
> I wish I had studied hard for my tests.

and **would** for the future wishes like expression #2. Does that make the expression #1 incorrect?

Can anyone explain to me which tense to use in my birthday wish-related context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In US use today, the verb *wish* is far more often used to express a ‘counterfactual’—that is, you *wish* you would get something you think it unlikely or impossible you *will* or *can* get:

> I wish someone would give me a Mercedes.
>   I wish I had a million dollars.
>   I wish I were an Oscar Meyer wiener.
>   I wish he was dead.

This is what your websites call ‘past tense’ or ‘past perfect’, but it’s not. It’s use of past *forms* to express unreal or impossible events; one technical term is *irrealis*. (The old-fashioned technical term is *subjunctive*.)

The once-ordinary indicative use is now found largely in old, more or less ritualized phrases:

> We wish you a Merry Christmas.
>   Wish upon a star. (*Wish I may, wish I might, First star I see tonight …*)
>   Wishing well
>   You may call me if you wish.
>   Best wishes, your friend, *Thor*.

In describing your desire for gifts you have a realistic chance of receiving, we say *hope* now, with the complement in the indicative:

> I hope I’m going to get a new laptop from my parents.
>   I hope I get Super Bowl tickets.
>   I hope somebody gets me a subscription to the *OED*.
>   I hope I clean up.

In announcing your desire to prospective donors we say *would like* (*I want* is a little bit too forthright).

> I’d like Super Bowl tickets.
>   I sure would like a Kindle for my birthday.
>   I’d really *really* like a date with Emma Watson. Failing that, with the redhead in my Psych class.

Comment: Isn't the "want to do something" meaning still perceived in "You may call Emma Watson, if you wish."?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, but again that's a stock phrase, a phatic ornament.

Comment: Still, it is better to point that out, before the OP thinks _wish_ (as verb) is used only for something that is unlikely/impossible to happen/get.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Good point; I will add it.